# Как объединить лексемы полученные командой strtok

Tags: c++, строки

Я пытаюсь собрать лексемы в один символьный массив при помощи конкатенации, но выходит какой-то бред:

```
char str[80], str2[80];
scanf("%s", str);

cout << "Разделение строки " << str << " на лексемы\n";
char * pch = strtok(str, "Cc");
for (int i=0; pch != NULL; i++)
{

        cout << pch << endl;
        strcat(str2, pch);
        pch = strtok(NULL, "Cc");

}
strcat(str2, "\0");


system("pause");
return 0;
```

Comment: Думаю мало кто знает что значит "лексемы". Дайте пример того что вы хотите получить и что получаете на выходе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы должны инициализировать массив `str2` строкой

```
str2[80];
str2[0] = '\0';
```

перед выполнением конкатенации.

А данное предложение

```
strcat(str2, "\0");
```

можно удалить за ненадобностью.

Также в этом цикле переменная `i` не используется

```
for (int i=0; pch != NULL; i++)
```

Поэтому было бы лучше объявить цикл как

```
while ( pch )
```

Comment: А дописываться токены будут после перед\0 или нужно делать strrev?

Comment: @losty strcat дописывает новую строку в конец текущей строки.